# Customizing SOAP of WCF Web Service Reference

Tags: wcf, serialization, soap, svcutil.exe

I am using automatically generated WCF Web Service Reference in my application to send SOAP requests to remote host. I am facing a problem similar to the one described here: [Custom Message Formatting in WCF to add all Namespaces to the SOAP Envelope](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Apr/02/Custom-Message-Formatting-in-WCF-to-add-all-Namespaces-to-the-SOAP-Envelope)

Described in this article solution I tried to use to solve my problem but did not succeed.
Thing is it looks like response class has to be inherited from the `Message` class. But in my case it was generated automatically.

What shall I do? Maybe it is possible to force svcutil to generate response class inherited from Message?

Answer (score 0):

The class you refer to might not the Message class the author says. With the `Message Inspector` or `Message Formatter`, we could intercept the SOAP message communicating with the server.
Please refer to my example written in these posts.
[How can I add a namespace to soap envelope in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53706539/how-can-i-add-a-namespace-to-soap-envelope-in-c-sharp/53719922#53719922)
[WCF Add Namespace Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52854540/wcf-add-namespace-attributes/52890091#52890091)
In contrast to the blog, I intercept the SOAP message with `MessageInspector`, instead of `MessageFormatter`. However, the principle is the same, using an interface implementation provided by the WCF framework to access the SOAP message. When we get the SOAP message, we can read it and modify it.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.